# Query only existing elements in an ArrayField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)

Post.objects.create(name='a', tags=['1'])
Post.objects.create(name='b', tags=['1', '2'])
Post.objects.create(name='c', tags=['1', '2','3'])
```

How to query tags=[2,1]?

Query tags contain only the results of 1 and 2

Comment: ```python
Post.objects.filter(tags__contains=['1','2'],tags__contained_by=['1','2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contains) in the filter.

Example for your case:

```py
Post.objects.filter(tags__contains=['1','2'])
```

Comment: I just want to find out name=b but this will find out name=b and name=c

Comment: Query with  tags__contains and tags__contained_by together